# How to send a notification in an android service?

Tags: android, mysql, service, notifications

In my android application, I have a server part containing a mysql database. I want to create a service whose role is to detect an update of a field. When the service detects a change in a table, it sends a notification to the user. I have not started writing the code but I have some questions to understand how the service works:

1) For access to the database I used `AsyncTask`, do I have to call this class in the `onStartCommand` method of the `service` ?

2) and for sending the notification, do I write its code in the `onPostExecute`method ?

3) Is the use of `BroadCast` mandatory ?
Thanks.

Comment: implement FCM to send notifications and recieve it in reciever class and then show it

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Comment: Thanks for the reply ,is there other solution with android service ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by using `BroadCast`,`Service` and `AlarmManager`.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to advise you to implement Firebase FCM notification to not consume the android resources for nothing.
good luck.

Comment: but my database should be in mysql server

Comment: You can use any database

Comment: see this link: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/